# get_term_by with a variable

Tags: taxonomy, slug, variables

I have a Custom template with a custom query. I want to use additional information about the current taxonomy > description and name (and use it in the HEAD, desc, keywords,  etc...)

```
<?php 
$productvariable = $_GET['product'];

$term = get_term_by('slug', $productvariable, 'mytaxonomy');
$mytitle = $term->name;
$mydesc = $term->description;
?>
```

- How do i make the variable safe from url to get_term_by ($value)?
- And what if there is no match is it possible to use ELSE?
- Is it possible to use the values inside HEAD (header.php)?

> Is there a security issue when using a GET variable from url with get_term_by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can look at line 874 in /wp-includes/taxonomy.php for the function itself. the value has `stripslashes` applied and then it's used in a prepared statement, so I'd say it's safe. but there's nothing stopping you from checking the value yourself first if you know what parameters it will always fall within, like `ctype_alnum` or something. then check if(empty($term)), to see if anything matched and print something else if not.